# Revising Python Code to format output of program

Tags: python

My current Python code returns this:

```
Employee Details:
    Employee Name: John Smith, Department: Accounting, Weekly Pay: $2511.25
    Employee Name: Mary Smith, Department: Finance, Weekly Pay: $2500
    Employee Name: Justin White, Department: Marketing, Weekly Pay: $2000.0

Total Weekly Pay: $7011.25
```

And I would like it to return this:

```
Employee Type      Employee Name  Department     Weekly Pay
-------------      -------------  ----------     ----------
Hourly Paid        John Smith     Accounting     $   1281.25
Salary Paid        Mary Smith     Finance        $   2500.00
Commission Paid    Justin White   Marketing      $   2000.00

Total Weekly Pay:$5781.25
```

How would I change the code? Python attached below:

Main function:

```py
import employee
def total_pay(employees):
    '''Take employee list as parameter
    Return total paid amount'''
    total=0.0
    for x in employees:
        total+=x.pay()
    return total

def print_employee_list(employees):
    '''Display all employee details'''
    for x in employees:
        print('\t',x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    '''Main method Create each subclass object'''
    commissionpaid=employee.CommissionPaid(500,50000)
    commissionpaid.set_name('Justin White')
    commissionpaid.set_department('Marketing')
    hourlypaid=employee.HourlyPaid(20.5,55)
    hourlypaid.set_name('John Smith')
    hourlypaid.set_department('Accounting')
    salarypaid=employee.SalaryPaid(2500)
    salarypaid.set_name('Mary Smith')
    salarypaid.set_department('Finance')
    employees=[hourlypaid,salarypaid,commissionpaid]
    #display employee details
    print('Employee Details:')
    print_employee_list(employees)
    #Total salary
    print('\nTotal Weekly Pay: $',total_pay(employees))
Modules:

#create a super class Employee
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name="",department=""):
        ''' Constructor assign values to attributes'''
        self.__name=name
        self.__department=department
    def get_name(self):
        '''Return name of the employee'''
        return self.__name
    def get_department(self):
        '''Return department of the employee'''
        return self.__department
    def set_name(self,name):
        '''Set employee name'''
        self.__name=name
    def set_department(self,department):
        '''set department where employee working'''
        self.__department=department
    def pay(self):
        '''Return salary of employee'''
        return 0.0
    def __str__(self):
        '''Return employee details'''
        return "Employee Name: "+self.__name+", Department: "+self.__department

#Create subclass CommissionPaid
class CommissionPaid(Employee):
    def __init__(self,base_rate=0.0,sales=0.0):
        '''Initialize attributes'''
        super().__init__()
        self.__base_rate=base_rate
        self.__sales=sales
    def get_base_rate(self):
        '''Return base rate of he employee'''
        return self.__base_rate
    def get_sales(self):
        '''Return sales amount'''
        return self.__sales
    def set_base_rate(self,base_rate):
        '''set base rate of the employee pay'''
        self.__base_rate=get_base_rate
    def set_sales(self,sales):
        '''set sales amount of the employee'''
        self.__sales=sales
    def pay(self):
        '''Calculate and return payment of commission based employee'''
        commission=0.0
        if self.__sales>30000:
            commission=self.__sales*.03
        elif self.__sales>=5000 and self.__sales<=30000:
            commission=self.__sales*.01
        return self.__base_rate+commission
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+", Weekly Pay: $"+str(self.pay())

#Create subclass HourlyPaid
class HourlyPaid(Employee):
    def __init__(self,hourly_rate=0.0,hours=0.0):
        '''Set attributes of the class'''
        super().__init__()
        self.__hourly_rate=hourly_rate
        self.__hours=hours
    def get_hourly_rate(self):
        '''Return hourly payment rate of the employee'''
        return self.__hourly_rate
    def get_hours(self):
        '''Return hours the employee worked'''
        return self.__hours
    def set_hourly_rate(self,hourly_rate):
        '''Set hourly rate of the employee'''
        self.__hourly_rate=hourly_rate
    def set_hours(self,hours):
        '''Set hours employee worked'''
        self.__hours==hours
    def pay(self):
        '''calculate payment'''
        if self.__hours<=40:
            return self.__hourly_rate*self.__hours
        else:
            return (self.__hourly_rate*40)+(self.__hourly_rate*(self.__hours)*1.5)
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+", Weekly Pay: $"+str(self.pay())
#Create subclass SalryPaid
class SalaryPaid(Employee):
    def __init__(self,salary):
        '''Set attributes'''
        super().__init__()
        self.__salary=salary
    def set_salary(self,salary):
        '''set salry'''
        self.__salary=salary
    def get_salary(self):
        '''Get salary'''
        return self.__salary
    def pay(self):
        '''calculate pay amount'''
        return self.__salary
    def __str__(self):
        return super().__str__()+", Weekly Pay: $"+str(self.pay())
```

Answer (score 2):

You should decouple data and presentation. Delete all those print and just model that data in your classes. Then create a script that takes all those instances and format it as you want.

It will be much more easier, but if after doing that you still do not know how to do it, post again the new code.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look exactly the way you want.. but it should give you the idea... This approach is pretty limited because column widths are fixed size and anything larger will be cut off.  But to dynamically size the columns would require quite a bit more work.

```
# Here, instead of duplicating all your code, I'll just dummy up some data to show you how the printing works...
from decimal import Decimal as D

employees = [
    { 'type': 'Hourly Paid',
      'name': 'John Smith',
      'dept': 'Accounting',
      'pay_wk': D('1281.25')
    },{
      'type': 'Salary Paid',
      'name': 'Mary Smith',
      'dept': 'Finance',
      'pay_wk': D('2500.00')
    }
]

fmt = "%-18.18s %-18.18s %-18.18s %s%17.17s"
underline = '--------------------'

print(fmt % ('Employee Type', 'Employee Name', 'Department', ' ', 'Weekly Pay'))
print(fmt % (underline, underline, underline, '-', underline))

for emp in employees:
    print(fmt % (emp['type'], emp['name'], emp['dept'], '$', emp['pay_wk']))
```

Output:

```
Employee Type      Employee Name      Department                 Weekly Pay
------------------ ------------------ ------------------ ------------------
Hourly Paid        John Smith         Accounting         $          1281.25
Salary Paid        Mary Smith         Finance            $          2500.00
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without hardcoding the employee details? For example, by calling the subclass objects?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I just hard coded it for the example.  Imagine that instead of `employees` being a `List` of `Dict`s, it was a `List` of `Employee` instances.  Then, where I have `emp['name']` in my example, you'd use `emp.get_name()`.